# dataTables read columns from ajaxsource

Tags: jquery, datatables

Can [DataTables](http://datatables.net) read columns (names) list from its ajaxSource?

I mean that I define columns in my `PHP` file and pass them with data, then `dataTables` parses them and create the table (full dynamically)

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665309/jquery-datatables-get-columns-from-json)!

Answer (score 0):

if your ajaxSource is something like :

```
           { 
            "aaData": [
             {
              a:"Trident",
              b:"Internet Explorer 4.0",
              c:"Win 95+",
              d:4,
              e:"X"
             } // [...]
           ],
           "aoColumns": [
            {
                "mData": "d",
                "sDefaultContent": 0
            },
            {
                "mData": "a",
                "sDefaultContent": "-"
            } //[...]
            ]}
```

you can do this call :

```
         $.getJSON('ajaxSource.php',function(json) {
                  json.bDestroy = true;
                  $('#example').dataTable(json);
         });
```